# WCF ASYNC PROCESSING

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I have a WCF service method which returns an object Employee details. Employee details class has two attributes one is payment and second one is employee details.
Now in WCF method both payment and employee details are calculated in two separate methods, which are running in parallel and doing their task without any dependency on another. 
Now i want to change the WCF method so that it will return both the objects (Payment, Employee Details) separately from the same method and for the same request asynchronously.

For example,
When one request is coming to the WCF method it will call Employee details method and Payment method simultaneously. Now if the Payment method completes its processing then i want to sent the response with payment object immediately without waiting for the employee method to complete processing, and later when employee method done with its processing i will then sent the Employee Details object separately.

Is there any approach in WCF to accomplish the above scenario?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think you just need wcf duplex communication here, just to push Employee Details with callback from server to client.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, but would wcf duplex work with JQuery Ajax?